# Is it possible to change the source of an iframe without page postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, asp.net-ajax, src

I just wanted to know, 
is it possible to change the source of an iframe without page postback?
if yes, then how.

Comment: You could for instance use jquery.load() function :)

Comment: please give any demo or sample code.

Comment: Check jquery documentation and do it yourself , it is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery.attr() method, you can change the src parameter.

```
$("#myifrm").attr("src","your url here");
```

To see a working sample, take a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/YCDtj/

Comment: That reloads the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting your question right, answer is no.

If you will change the source of an iframe, a new page will load in it.

If your markup is

```
<iframe id='myframe' src='http://www.abc.com' ></iframe>
```

And you do,

```
document.getElementById('myframe').src = 'http://www.xyz.com';
```

it will reload and open xyz.com.

Comment: And if I just want to replace a part or a parameter of my iFrame src?

Comment: You should try it to test it. Replacing the hash should not reload but replacing the parameter may.

Answer (score 0):

For the first load :
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var myIframe = document.getElementById('yourIFrameID');

```
if(myIframe != undefined || myIframe != null)
myIframe.src = "newSource";
});
```

AND call following setIFrameSrc() function from any place you want to.

```
function setIFrameSrc(newURL)
{
var myIframe = document.getElementById('yourIFrameID'); 

if(myIframe != undefined || myIframe != null)
myIframe.src = newURL;

}
```